# Wifi not working when connecting two PC with crossover cable

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, internet

**What i want to accomplish:**

I have two PCs with Windows 7 Pro. I want those computer to be connected in order to have them sharing their files. Each one of them must work on some big files (videos and photos) on the other PC, hence the connection must be pretty fast.

**What i did:**

I connected those pc with a cross-over ethernet cable and then configured their LAN network this way:

PC A

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.131
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.132
```

PC B

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.132
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.131
```

And they work pretty well!

Here are the ipconfig of each computer:

[IPCONFIG PC with WIFI](http://pastebin.com/qzxRg2Sp)

[IPCONFIG PC without WIFI](http://pastebin.com/FVLnSdN6)

**The problem**

When they are connected, internet through wifi (done through a PCI card) doesn't work on any of them. The PC sees the wifi network, it connects to it, but internet doesn't work. I get this message on every browser: `dns_probe_finished_bad_config`.
As soon as i unplug the crossover cable, internet works.

How can i make them connected to each other and to internet?

Comment: What is the subnet of the WiFi network?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 how can i find it? Also, how can my LAN connection influence my WIFI connection?

Comment: You can get all your IP addresses, masks etc. with `ipconfig /all`...

Answer (score 1):

Have a better understanding of what the networking settings do.

Specifically, the term "Gateway" is a device that lets you talk to a network.  In large companies, you can have a gateway device (a router) that lets you talk to a specific small network.  The "Default Gateway" is the gateway gets used to talk to the rest of the Internet.

So when you connect this crossover cable, the network connection's settings are active, and each computer has settings that say traffic for the Internet needs to go over the crossover cable.  You're never getting that traffic to the Internet.

The solution is simple: just leave the "Default Gateway" field blank on the network connections that have the crossover cable.  (And, of course, make sure the Wi-Fi connection has the correct details.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. But if I leave the "default gateway" field blank on both computers, will they be able to browse each other files again? (I'm asking now, because i can do such test only tomorrow)

Comment: Yes.  Computers will realize the 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2 are both same subnet, which goes from 192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.255 because subnet mask specified that size.  (1st and last address are "unusable".)  People often make the subnet mask a /24, so they can identify subnets just from the last number.  In the case of a crossover cable, you could use a subnet mask of 255.255.255.252 with those addresses, which specifies a subnet big enough for 192.0.0.0 - 192.0.0.3.  The WiFi connections will need to have their own separate Default Gateway setting, usually set by a DHCP server on the WAP

Comment: I'm just continuing to be bothered by the phrase, `if I leave the "default gateway" field blank on both computers`.  That just kind of makes it sound like "default gateway" is a computer-wide setting.  I just want to make clear that the "default gateway" setting is commonly located by the configuration details that are specific to each network connection.  So the thing to blank out is the "default gateway" setting for *only* the network connection that uses the crossover cable (on both computers), but **not** the "default gateway" settings used by the Wi-Fi adapters

Comment: I tried your solution. Now internet over WIFI works, but the pcs cannot communicate with each other anymore. The LAN network connection is marked as "unidentified network" (i translated it from italian, hope it's correct).
Their IP addresses are different from any other address on the network (ipconfig /all). WHat do you suggest?

Comment: Sounds like some mismatched settings.  Run `IPConfig/all` on both computers and paste results into question.

Comment: Just did it! They are in italian, but it won't be hard to understand them

Comment: On PC with WiFi, the "LAN wireless" is using 192.168.1.35 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0, which means it uses the subnet from 192.168.1.0 through 192.168.1.255.  That conflicts with the Ethernet LAN's 192.168.1.131 and 192.168.1.132 addresses.  Avoid the conflict.  e.g., set the Ethernet LANs to use 172.17.1.131 and 172.17.1.132 (since those are also usable for private LANs, per [IETF BCP5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp5)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37166/discussion-between-alberto-fontana-and-toogam).